# Why does this wmctrl script not move the windows

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command

```
wmctrl -l | awk '{ if ($4 == "Android") print $4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "}' | while read -r line;do wmctrl -r \"$line\" -e 1,0,0,100,100; done
```

Ok I know that is a bit hard to read, let me break it up.

```
wmctrl -l
```

will list all the windows controlled by wmctrl. My output is the following.

```
0x00800024 -1 DarkNetLab xfce4-panel
0x02c00006 -1 DarkNetLab Desktop
0x06806427  0 DarkNetLab mac@DarkNetLab: /opt/Analysis
0x06000008  0        N/A Emulator
0x06000003  0        N/A Android Emulator - droid8:5554
0x0b800009  0        N/A Emulator
0x0b800003  0        N/A Android Emulator - droid11:5556
0x05400009  0        N/A Emulator
0x05400003  0        N/A Android Emulator - droid9:5558
```

Then the awk (`| awk '{ if ($4 == "Android") print $4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "}'`) grabs all the lines who's 4th element is "Android" and prints the next 4 elements producing the following...

```
Android Emulator - droid8:5554
Android Emulator - droid11:5556
Android Emulator - droid9:5558
```

These are all the correct windows I want to move and need to be passed in with the -r argument for wmctrl

Finally I use `| while read -r line;do wmctrl -r \"$line\" -e 1,0,0,100,100; done` to use each window like `Android Emulator - droid8:5554` to move the window with the wmctrl command.

NO WINDOWS MOVE!!

If I change the code to `wmctrl -l | awk '{ if ($4 == "Android") print $4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "}' | while read -r line;do echo "wmctrl -r \"$line\" -e 1,0,0,100,100"; done` in order to echo the command that should be executed, I get the following.

```
wmctrl -r "Android Emulator - droid8:5554" -e 1,0,0,0,100,100
wmctrl -r "Android Emulator - droid11:5556" -e 1,0,0,0,100,100
wmctrl -r "Android Emulator - droid9:5558" -e 1,0,0,0,100,100
```

If I then copy and paste any of the lines into terminal and execute the terminal runs it correctly and moves the window.. So I'm wondering why the script doesn't work!

Thanks in advance for the help, my guess is this is an issue with when/how bash evals commands and substitutes values for variables.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: wow, you the man. Can't believe that was it lol.  If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the escapes around "$line", i.e. change `...do wmctrl -r \"$line\"...` to just `...do wmctrl -r "$line"...`.